# Mysql database sometimes enter blank rows when submitted via php otherwise it works well. How to avoid this?

Tags: php, html, mysql

FORM CODE -

```
<form method="POST" action="shareexperience.php" id="contactForm"  name="sentMessage" target="formsaved">
<br/><textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="views" id="views" placeholder="Views About Your Profession">
</textarea> <br/>
<textarea rows="5" cols="40" name="advice" id="advice" placeholder="Advice 4 Students">
</textarea> <br/>
Wanna Be A Guide 4 Child 
<input type="radio" id="yes" name="guide" value="Yes" checked> Yes </input>
<input type="radio" id="No" name="guide" value="No" > No </input> 
<br/><input type="text" name="name" id="professionalname" placeholder="Name">
<input type="text" name="email" id="professionalemail" placeholder="Email Id"> <br/>
<br/><input type="submit" value="Share & Nominate" onclick="saveexperience()"> 
</form>


PHP CODE-

<? php
$con=mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error()); 
 $db=mysql_select_db(DB_NAME,$con) or die("Failed to connect to MySQL: " .mysql_error());
 //inserting Record to the database
 $name = $_POST['name']; 
 $email = $_POST['email'];
$views = $_POST['views'];
$advice = $_POST['advice'];
$guide=$_POST['guide'];
 $query = "INSERT INTO professionals(name,email,views,advice,guide)VALUES('$name','$email', '$views','$advice','$guide')"; 
 $result = mysql_query($query); 
mysql_close($con); 
?>
```

Target formsaved has been used to avoid redirection by using html tag iframe as followed below-

```
<iframe name="formsaved" height="30px" width="300px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"> </iframe>
```

Sometimes data enter fines but sometimes it doesn't work 
You can check my website as well - guidance4future.in/nominate

Note:- onclick has been used to disable one of the html tags in the page further...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: **WARNING**: If you're just learning PHP, please, do not learn the obsolete [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) interface. It's awful and has been removed in PHP 7. A replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) helps explain best practices. Your user parameters are **not** [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) and you have severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) here.

Comment: In your table set field not null. And in your php check data.. if(empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($views) || empty($advice) || empty($guide)) die;

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, **please** do some sanity checks on your code! Someone could come along and delete your entire database right now...

I suspect that what's happening is that someone is clicking submit without entering anything in the form: in which case your code will just insert a blank row.

Do some checks first:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "database");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$name = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$views = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['views']);
$advice = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['advice']);
$guide = $mysqli->real_escape_string$_POST['guide']);

// Check for null fields
if( empty($name) || empty($email) || empty($views) || empty($advice) || empty($guide))
{
    print "Please fill in all fields!";
    // Show the form again here
}
else
{
     $query = "INSERT INTO professionals(name,email,views,advice,guide)VALUES('$name','$email', '$views','$advice','$guide')";
     $mysqli->query($query);
}
```

Comment: See prepared statements

Comment: Yeah that's probably worth looking into for the OP - I've not used PHP for a couple of  years so it sounds like I'm behind current best practice

Answer (score 0):

You should check the data before it is submitted to the database to make sure that all the fields were filled out properly.

```
if (!(empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['views']) || empty($_POST['advice']) || empty($_POST['guide']))){
    // do your stuff here
} else {
    // error stuff
}
```

Additionally, as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845109/mysql-database-sometimes-enter-blank-rows-when-submitted-via-php-otherwise-it-wo#comment61259774_36845109), you should look into using PDO for your database operations.